# How to execute dynamic SQL statement inside Postgres sql script

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic, execute

Below is my script. I used **Execute** command to run the dynamic sql statement that i created but it doesn't run and give an output. It doesn't give an error either. How can I run this sql statement inside postgres sql script?

```
DO $$
DECLARE sqlCommand varchar(1000);
 columnList varchar(75);

BEGIN
select  '"BRANCH_NAME", "ADDRESS1"' into columnList;

select concat('SELECT ' , columnList , ' FROM "TESTSCHEMA"."BRANCH" ')  into sqlCommand;

raise info 'COMMAND %', sqlCommand;
execute sqlCommand;

END $$;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example is safe, but if you are dealing with user input, always use the `format` function to construct the SQL string.

Anyway, your problem is that the `EXECUTE` statement has no `INTO` clause with a destination for the query results, si they are simply discarded.